# Wordpress Assign an Attachment to a post

Tags: wordpress, image, attachment

I'm trying to assign an existing attachment (say it is attached to another post already) to a post, and also remove existing attachments from a post.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Couldn't find a suitable solution in this short time span, so I result to a custom field with image IDs separated by commas like so: 1034,1056,1127 and than simply loading those images (attached to posts or not) using get_posts(array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'include' => '1034,1056,1127,));

It's not the cleanest solution in the book, I'm sure, but it's quick and pretty elegant.

Comment: Good work, but please add your solution as an answer when you discover it yourself -- it's more keeping with Stack Overflow format and doesn't leave your question unanswered! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ll find the solution here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment